# How can I regenerate styles.css in Vaadin 8

Tags: vaadin, vaadin8

After modifying `styles.scss`, `Vaadin 8` does not recreate `styles.css`. If I completely remove `style.css`, the application does not create this file and I get a 404 error in the browser.

The application does not run in production mode and I am using a theme. According to the documentation, this file should be created:

```
If the on-the-fly compilation does not seem to work, ensure that your build script 
has not generated a pre-compiled CSS file. If a styles.css file is found by the 
servlet, the compilation is skipped. Disable theme compilation in your local 
development environment and delete the existing styles.css file to enable on-the-fly 
compilation.
```

Can, please, abybody tell me how to force Vaadin to create styles.css ?

Comment: What does the server log say? Have you tried creating the css with your build-tool (which you would have to do anyway, once you want your change to be rolled out)?  Does it appear once you revert your changes to the scss file?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the Maven goal `mvn vaadin:compile-theme` from the `vaadin-maven-plugin` to force the compilation of the styles CSS file. This is not something you usually want to do in development mode, as you'd want to have the on-the-fly theme compilation to do that for you. Quite often, the underlying problem is that a theme scss file contains a syntax error which prevents the compilation from succeeding.